# speech recognition in multiple form fields in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, speech-recognition

Im using localhost server for my website. I have integrated speech recognition in my form fields.
As I needed speech recognizer in every field of form therefore I used different view function for that and rendering back to same page. The speech is working perfectly but the problem is When I submit the form The speech recognition starts working however it should save that data into  database. When I donot use speech recognizer it is saving data perfectly but not with speech recognizer as it again starts to run speech algo.
I really do not know what should be done at this point.
**Form code**

```html
<form action="" method="POST" >
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="txtb" style="color:#022739">

       <input type="text" name="" value="{{p}}" readonly  style=" font-size: 15px;color:#022739;" >
      <input type="hidden" name="patientname" value="{{pid}}" readonly style=" font-size: 15px;color:#022739;" required="">
    </div>
        <div class="txtb" style="color:#022739">
             <input type="text" name="" value="{{doc}}" readonly style="  font-size: 15px;  color:#022739;">

      <input type="hidden" name="docname" value="{{docid}}"  readonly style=" font-size: 15px;color:#022739;" required="">
    </div>

        <div class="txtb" style="display:none;color:#022739">

      <input type="hidden" name="date" value="{{d}}" readonly style=" font-size: 15px;color:#022739;" required="">
    </div>


<div class="txtb" style="color:#022739">
      <input type="text" name="cal" value="{{sp}}" placeholder="Enter total calories"  style=" font-size: 15px;color:#022739;" required="" pattern="[0-9]+" >
      <a href="/speechCal"  style="font-family: FontAwesome"  >
         <i class="fa fa-microphone" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left:160px;"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
<div class="txtb" >
      <input placeholder="Breakfast" name="breakfast" value="{{sp2}}" required="" pattern="([^\s][A-z0-9À-ž\s]+)">
   <a href="/speechBreak"  style="font-family: FontAwesome"  >
         <i class="fa fa-microphone" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left:160px;"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
      <div class="txtb" >
      <input placeholder="Lunch" name="lunch" required="" value="{{sp3}}" pattern="([^\s][A-z0-9À-ž\s]+)">
            <a href="/speech3"  style="font-family: FontAwesome"  >
         <i class="fa fa-microphone" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left:160px;"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
<div class="txtb" >
      <input placeholder="Dinner" name="dinner" value="{{sp4}}" required="" pattern="([^\s][A-z0-9À-ž\s]+)">
   <a href="/speech4"  style="font-family: FontAwesome"  >
         <i class="fa fa-microphone" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left:160px;"></i>
      </a>
    </div>




    <a href="{% url 'nutchat' id=p %}"><input class="btn" type="submit" onclick="msg()" value="Send"/></a>

</form>
```

**views**

```
def speechCal(request):
    onlydate = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    field_name = 'id'
    obj = DocRecordnew.objects.get(firstname=request.session['firstname'])
    docid = getattr(obj, field_name)

    pid = pd()

    r3 = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("speak something")
        audio = r3.listen(source)
        r3.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    try:
        speak = r3.recognize_google(audio)
        print("prediction: " + r3.recognize_google(audio))
        global sp11

        def sp11():
            return speak


    except Exception:
        speak = "something went wrong"
        print("something went wrong")
    #return redirect('newnutritionistchat/?id='+pid)
    return render(request, 'newnutritionistchat.html', {'d': onlydate,'p': pid, 'doc': request.session['firstname'],'docid': docid, 'sp': speak})

        # return render(request, 'newdoctorchat.html', {​​'doc': request.session['firstname'],'pid':pid, 'docid': docid}​​)
def speechBreak(request):
    onlydate = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    field_name = 'id'
    obj = DocRecordnew.objects.get(firstname=request.session['firstname'])
    docid = getattr(obj, field_name)
    sp=sp11()
    p = pd()
    r3 = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("speak something")
        audio = r3.listen(source)
        r3.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    try:
        speak = r3.recognize_google(audio)
        print("prediction: " + r3.recognize_google(audio))
        global sp22

        def sp22():
            return speak
    except Exception:
        speak = "something went wrong"
        print("something went wrong")
    return render(request, 'newnutritionistchat.html', {'d': onlydate,'sp':sp,'doc': request.session['firstname'],'p':p ,'docid': docid, 'sp2': speak})


def speech3(request):
    onlydate = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    field_name = 'id'
    obj = DocRecordnew.objects.get(firstname=request.session['firstname'])
    docid = getattr(obj, field_name)
    sp2 = sp22()
    sp=sp11()

    p = pd()
    r3 = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("speak something")
        audio = r3.listen(source)
        r3.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    try:
        speak = r3.recognize_google(audio)
        print("prediction: " + r3.recognize_google(audio))
        global sp33

        def sp33():
            return speak
    except Exception:
        speak = "something went wrong"
        print("something went wrong")
    return render(request, 'newnutritionistchat.html', {'d': onlydate,'sp2':sp2,'sp':sp,'doc': request.session['firstname'],'p':p ,'docid': docid, 'sp3': speak})


def speech4(request):
    onlydate = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    field_name = 'id'
    obj = DocRecordnew.objects.get(firstname=request.session['firstname'])
    docid = getattr(obj, field_name)
    sp2 = sp22()
    sp = sp11()
    sp3=sp33()

    p = pd()
    r3 = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("speak something")
        audio = r3.listen(source)
        r3.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    try:
        speak = r3.recognize_google(audio)
        print("prediction: " + r3.recognize_google(audio))

    except Exception:
        speak = "something went wrong"
        print("something went wrong")
    return render(request, 'newnutritionistchat.html',{ 'd': onlydate,'sp3': sp3,'sp2': sp2, 'sp': sp, 'doc': request.session['firstname'], 'p': p, 'docid': docid, 'sp4': speak})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting your view into GET and POST requests like this

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    # get the template with the audio saving form ,, from forms.py
elif request.method == 'POST':
    # save the form into the database
```

Comment: actually problem is speech recognition starts reloading while submitting the form.  the form is same for both. speech recognition do is listen to voice user using and convert it into text and then that gets the result in that form field.

Comment: The reason I asked you to break your logic into GET and POST request. To break your business logic. once you are done recording your audio you want to POST ( Save) the file to your backend ( MODEL ) using ( voice_record = models.FileField() ) ONCE it the audio saved then you return the ( RESPONSE )